# Trouble in passsing form object to javascript from an hyperlink

Tags: javascript

```
<a href="javascript:SelectAll(this.form)">All </a>
<input type ="button" value ="test" onClick="SelectAll(this.form);" />


    <script ......>
    function SelectAll(form)
    {
        alert(form); 
    }
    </script>
```

method 1 produce an alert message 'undefined' while 2 method works fine by displaying form object . I'm very much aware that  anchor elements don't have a `form` property, that references the form , unlike input elements,but is there any alternative way to pass form object using hyperlink or is there any way to style the button to look like  an hyperlink

Thanks

Comment: Please enclose your code with the <code> tag

Comment: Please format the code in the question so we can read it easier

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
onClick="SelectAll(getParentForm(this));"

function getParentForm(el) {
  while(el = el.parentNode) {
    if(el.tagName.toLowerCase() === "form")
      return el;
  }

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the anchor is not a form control, it doesn't have a form property. You would need to find some other way to reference the form (or stick to a button, which is the right choice of control for something like this).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly?  I think your best approach is to not use an anchor element at all. It's not really a link, so that's actually a misuse of HTML.

Use a button element instead, which *does* have a form property.  If you *really* want it to look like a link, slap on a little CSS to make it look like one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
button.link {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

function SelectAll( f )
{
  alert( f );
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <form id="test">
    <button class="link" onclick="SelectAll(this.form)">All</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

But there are probably a dozen other ways to get a reference to the form element itself. If your form definition looked like this

```
<form id="test" name="tester">
```

and it's the only form on the page, here are some ways to obtain a reference to it

```
document.forms.tester
document.forms['tester']
document.forms[0]
document.getElementById( 'test' )
```

Comment: You should validate that HTML.

Comment: Uhhh, why?  it's just an example - I think it's extremely silly to validate every little snippet of HTML.  Ok, so I forgot the `</html>` and the `<button>` should be in another block element - big deal.  It gets the point across without being 100% valid markup.